# Is it correct to say: "to get to sth"?

Tags: grammar

> - How do you get to work?
> - I take the underground to work.
> - How do you get to school?
> - I walk to school.

---

Considering the questions, why are not the answers like these: "I take the underground *to {get to}* work", and "I walk *to {get to}* school"? **Which way are they correct, with or without "get to"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms are correct. In the questions, either the "get to" or another phrase (such as "travel to" or "go to") is needed to establish the subject as "transportation to work|school".
In the answers, since a specific mode of movement is spoken of, the phrases "walk to" and "take the underground to" can be used, and the added phrase "get to" is optional.

Comment: Mr. O'Flaherty, thank you for your response!